# getting blank page when printing with fop 1.1

Tags: java, printing, apache-fop

using fop1.1 , i'm trying to print a document using the intermediate file method disscussed in this section [fop intermediate format](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/0.95/output.html)

the problem is that it prints a blank page in the 3rd step .

this is the FO file i'm using for my tests :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:fox="http://xml.apache.org/fop/extensions">
   <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="all" page-height="5.4cm" page-width="9.56cm" margin-top="0cm" margin-bottom="0cm" margin-left="0cm" margin-right="0cm">
         <fo:region-body margin-top="0cm" margin-bottom="0cm" background-color="transparent" />
      </fo:simple-page-master>
   </fo:layout-master-set>
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="all">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
         <fo:block>
            <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" top="5px" left="11px" height="30px" width="300px" overflow="hidden">
               <fo:block font-weight="normal" font-style="italic" font-family="Arial">852147</fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
            <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" top="50px" left="10px" height="30px" width="300px" overflow="hidden">
               <fo:block font-weight="bold" font-style="normal" font-family="Arial" font-size="10pt">nabil</fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
            <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" top="100px" left="10px" height="30px" width="300px" overflow="hidden">
               <fo:block font-weight="bold" font-style="normal" font-family="Arial" font-size="10pt">madara</fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
         </fo:block>
      </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- $Id: fop.xconf 1339442 2012-05-17 01:42:56Z gadams $ -->



<!-- NOTE: This is the version of the configuration -->
<fop version="1.1">
<fonts>
      <auto-detect/>
      </fonts>

<!-- Strict user configuration -->
  <strict-configuration>true</strict-configuration>

  <!-- Strict FO validation -->
  <strict-validation>true</strict-validation>

  <!-- Base URL for resolving relative URLs -->
  <base>.</base>

  <!-- Font Base URL for resolving relative font URLs -->
  <font-base>./</font-base>


  <source-resolution>72</source-resolution>

  <target-resolution>72</target-resolution>


  <default-page-settings height="11in" width="8.26in"/>


 <renderers>
    <renderer mime="application/pdf">
      <filterList>
        <!-- provides compression using zlib flate (default is on) -->
        <value>flate</value>



      </filterList>

      <fonts>
      <auto-detect/>

      </fonts>


    </renderer>
</renderers>

</fop>
```

steps :

1. `fop  -c  cfg.xml -fo myfile.fo -at application/pdf myfile.at.xml`
2. `fop -c cfg.xml -atin myfile.at.xml -pdf myfile.pdf`  (the pdf file is generated correctly)
3. `fop -atin myfile.at.xml -print` (  a blank page is printed using pdf creator)

Comment: What do you mean it "prints a blank page in the third step". There is an issue where opening pdf files in IE returns a blank page so I'm trying to understand if this is the same problem or if you get some stuff printed by your `FOP` and not others. You may need to provide some more context in order to get an answer.

Comment: please take a look at the update providing more context , thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with the AWT renderer (the print renderer uses the AWT renderer) in FOP 1.1. I tried your example using the following as your step 3:

```
fop -atin myfile.at.xml -awt
```

I noticed the same result - a blank page. (NOTE: to get the AWT render to work on Windows, you will need to edit `fop.bat` so that `-Djava.awt.headless=false`).

I found it strange that no errors were logged to the console, and I couldn't find any bugs reported in FOP's JIRA instance. So I decided to have a play with FOP 1.0.

**The workaround** - download FOP 1.0 instead of FOP 1.1. Use the following as your **Step 3**:

```
fop -atin myfile.at.xml -print all
```

**NOTE:** The **all** argument is used to print all pages. Omitting this argument fails in 1.0, but has been fixed in 1.1.

Hope the above is a workable solution for you! It seems very much as though there's an unresolved/unreported issue with FOP 1.1 and the AWT renderer. :(